# Javascript object returning undefined inside a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, object

Today I was trying to get some data from mysql with a function, and when i console.log the values inside the function, all returns properly, but if i `return <value>`, it returns undefined (`rows[0]` is an object), for example:

```js
function getData(userID, guildID) {
    connection.connect();
    this.guildID = guildID ?? null
    this.userID = userID ?? null
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM data_${this.guildID} WHERE id = '${this.userID}'`, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        connection.end()
        this.data = rows[0]
        return this.data;
    })
}
```

returns undefined when i `console.log(getData(etc, etc))`

but if i do:

```js
function getData(userID, guildID) {
    connection.connect();
    this.guildID = guildID ?? null
    this.userID = userID ?? null
    connection.query(`SELECT * FROM data_${this.guildID} WHERE id = '${this.userID}'`, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        connection.end()
        this.data = rows[0]
        console.log(this.data);
    })
}
```

it works perfectly fine, which logs:

```js
RowDataPacket {
  id: '573991320897716224',
  bank: '0',
  wallet: '0',
  unlimited: '0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the rows data is inside the callback of `connection.query` and your `getData` function is finished executing itself.

In simple terms what's happening right now is that you are expecting `getData` function to return the result but the result is in the callback which has not finished execution by the time your `getData` function is executed

What you may do is create a promise and resolve it once the callback has finished retrieving the data. e.g

```
async function getData(userID, guildID) {
    connection.connect();
    this.guildID = guildID ?? null
    this.userID = userID ?? null
    return await queryDatabase(connection, {guildID: this.guildID, userID: this.userID})
}


function queryDatabase(connectionObj, payload) {
    return new promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connectionObj.query(`SELECT * FROM data_${payload.guildID} WHERE id = '${payload.userID}'`, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
        connectionObj.end()
        resolve(rows[0]);
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! this solved my issue, appreciate it <3